# Recovered JPEG files won't open

Tags: data-recovery, jpeg, file-recovery

I have recovered some photos with Recuva and a lot of them have been recovered fine, however there are some that only half the picture shows and the other half is just grey, then there are others that won't show a picture for the thumbnail.

When I check properties it says the size, and each picture shows a different size so I assume there is content.

Please help! If I can load the pictures up somewhere for someone to check over please let me know how and where.

Comment: If you are using recuva there must have been some sort of catastrophic event prior to this, during which portions of the picture were lost or unrecoverable.  The moral to the story is don't keep valuable files on just one computer, put them somewhere else too... Like Dropbox

Comment: Recovering data never guarantees a perfect recovery. It gets you what it can, and it may not be right.  So your (recovered) pictures are corrupted, the size reports (etc.) don't matter, as the data contained is incorrect.  You'll have to restore them from a good backup, or accept they are gone forever.

Comment: The proposed duplicate addresses how to identify corrupted images.  In this question, identifying them doesn't appear to be a problem.  The (implied) problem is successful recovery.

Answer (score 1):

Every file that gets deleted may be overwritten by other files. Though you were able to recover some files, there is no warranty that all images survived the deletion. In your case it looks like your pictures got damaged while they were deleted.

You can try with tools like [these](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/repair-and-fix-corrupted-images/) to repair your broken JPEG-Files.